Compiler errors that I can't suppress
I'm compiling my React/TypeScript app using tsc --build and, while it worked well during development with TypeScript errors ignored, I'm encountering numerous errors in build mode. I initially attempted to suppress these errors, but I've realized I need to fix them instead.
However, I'm facing some particularly cryptic error messages, like the one below:
error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"button" | "submit" | "reset"'.                           

           <button
               type="button"                                                                                                                                   
               ~~~~                                

  node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3148:9                                                                                                                  
    3148         type?: "submit" | "reset" | "button" | undefined;                                                                                             
                 ~~~~                                                                                                                                          
    The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'


It's not a matter of "Type X is not assignable to type X"; rather, it's complaining that I'm providing a string type, which is larger than the required type. However, the actual type I'm providing is not a string—it precisely matches the required type!
I'm adding a bunch of // @ts-ignore as a workaround.
Could anyone help me understand the root cause of these errors? What might be causing TypeScript to produce such messages when the type actually matches?

What version of typescript, react, and @types/react are you using?

It would be helpful if you could share a micro repository with the issue or make the code a minimum reproducible example, then we can check how you're setting up TS. It would prob be helpful to you as well, to have a super simple setup where you could iterate over.

Definitely looks like an issue with your TypeScript setup somehow, and not the code, and it's kinda hard to give advice from afar.
Some options to try:

A nicer workaround, is probably to coerce a smaller type to , either with type=("button" as const) or type=("button" as "button" | "submit" | "reset")
Try cleaning your build/dev setup to any extent possible, ie: remove build products, maybe upto and including re-installing all packages, or recloning the repo and reinstalling.


I think you will agree with me that it would be quite surprising if I got any news with your first option to try. I lost the buggy setup after fixing it, so I can't really try any more experiments on it. So you were right to suggest cleaning up the setup, but I don't accept this answer, both because I still don't know what exactly was wrong with my setup (or how to check it, or even how to make a correct setup!), and because it seems like the problem was working with an npm workspace-like setup without actually setting up npm workspaces in the proper way, which nobody suggested.
